# Why a function need to be static if access by a reference variable?

Tags: java

i am trying tto understand why this code is not working when using a non static modifier

Core.java

```java
package Core;

import java.io.Console;

public  class Core {
    public static Reference out;
}

class Reference {
    public void print(int t) {
        System.out.printf("%d", t);
    }
}
```

and
CoreB.java

```java
package Core;

import java.io.Console;

public class CoreB {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Core.out.Print(5);
    }
}
```

Here will give me the error of Cannot invoke  because "Core.Core.out" is null
but if i put a static modifier on the print method will work fine
Core.java

```java
package Core;

import java.io.Console;

public  class Core {
    public static Reference out;
}

class Reference {
    public static void print(int t) {
        System.out.printf("%d", t);
    }
}
```

my question is, why on others lines for example, System.out.printf, where **out** is static but **printf** not, and i must use static on both ??.

Comment: is there supposed to be a difference in 1st core.java and 2nd core.java?

Comment: yes, sorry, edited (static in method)

Comment: @Herroo So I was looking at the docs for the System class here: https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/System-source.html , and it seems that you’ve replicated it correctly in your first example except for the fact that the System class if final and that the out variable is also final. I think this is where the problem is with your first example. Try changing your out variable to final and/or your Core class to final

Comment: thanks @user16320675, that worked btw how is using a variable for reference formal called ? (i am looking on google for study it more) ?

Answer (score 0):

Without `static`, an instance of object `Reference` needs to be initialized to call `print()`, that is why `NullPointerException` is thrown, cause no object of `Preference` is created.

With `static`, you can call the static field and method through class name.

You can read more about static here
[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: yes, but i would need to use  (Reference obj = new Reference(); obj.Print(5);) so, how is System.out.printf working if is not static printf? because you dont need to use (out obj = new out(); obj.printf ("5");)

Comment: System.out is a static field.

Comment: yes but printf() is not static, and in my code if print() is not static is not working, why  System.out.printf() works but Core.out.Print() no ? if both (core.out and system.out) are static and ( printf() and print() ) no ?